# Value not changing in useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Com() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    //here is some code that I want to run only once.
    //edit: bcz I want to creating variable here and access in setInterval
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(x);
      //problem is here x not updating
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  function change() {
    console.log(x);
    // incrementing x on every click
    setX(x + 1);
  }
  return <button onClick={change}>Change X</button>;
}
export default Com;
```

I want to update value of x in useEffect Hooks.
If I use x as dependency array, All code in useEffect runs again that I don't want.

Comment: OK, can you clarify what you want to achieve? According to your description, you would like to "update the value of `x` in the`useEffct` hook". Yet, in your example, you are merely outputting the value of `x` in the hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the old/current state by passing a function to `setState`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setX(oldX => /* do something about it */)
  }, 1000);

  // don't forget to do clean up
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, a variable may store two types of values: primitive and reference.

JavaScript provides six primitive types as undefined, null, boolean, number, string, and symbol , and a reference type object.

Because x is a number (which is a primitive) it is being passed by value and not by reference.
And because it is passes only once, the value is passed only once.
If you want to pass it by reference you can wrap x in an object.

```
const [x, setX] = useState({value:0});
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. According to your suggestion, each time the button is clicked, the interval will be recreated, which is exactly what he would like to avoid.

Comment: Why would the interval will be recreated? useEffect still runs only once, but this time it access a reference each time callback is invoke. Is setInterval is being called more that once?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your useEffect to something like this. Pretty much each second it clears the old timeout so and creates a new one so it should have the new x value

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(x);
    setX(x + 1)
  }, 1000);
  // Clear timeout if the component is unmounted
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking, although he did forget to clean up.

Comment: I just followed what the OP had in their own code, but have tweaked it to properly answer it.

Comment: He explicitly mentions he doesn't want to use x as a dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

useEfffect accepts an array of dependencies as second argument. Any dependent state/prop/context values used in useEffect needs to be passed down in this array.

example :

```
function App () {
 const [name, setName] = useState("")
 
 useEffect(() => {
     console.log("name ", name) // returns ""
 },[])

 
 useEffect(() => {
     console.log("name ", name) // returns  new value in name
 },[name])

 return (

  <div>
    {... some jsx}
  </div>
 )

}
```

In your case you are using `x` state in `useEffect`.So you need to pass `x` as dependency.

like this :

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    //here is some code that I want to run only once.
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(x);
      //problem is here x not updating
    }, 1000);
  }, [x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update a state using hooks that is related to the previous value, such as x + 1 relying on x, you should use a callback function when setting it.

This will ensure that it is always the most recent version of state that you are referring to.

```
setX(prevX => prevX + 1);
```

Also if you are only running the useEffect once then x won't update because it won't print out after the first time.

If you want it to print every time x changes then you need to add x as a dependency. The setInterval will only show the initial state of x because the useEffect is never getting the new value of it.

Try either of these. I would suggest the second one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(x);
    }, 1000);
  }, [x]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(x);
}, [x]);
```